# How to delete cookie after closing the tab while other tabs are open

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap

I'm implementing an asp.net core 3.1 project. My problem is I want when the user close the project tab meanwhile other tabs are open, the cookie goes to get deleted. Right now after running the project, while other tabs are open, after I close the tab that shows my program and rerun my project again, I don't need to login and the cookie isn't deleted. But I want in that situation to login as well. I appreciate if anyone tells me the expression I need to use to solve the issue. For implementing the project, I authenticate the user via ldap with the below expressions in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

services.AddControllersWithViews();

services.AddDbContext<CSDContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CSDContext")));


services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, LdapAuthenticationService>();
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
// Cookie settings

//set the cookie name here
options.Cookie.Name = "UserLoginCookie"; // Name of cookie
options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/UserAccessDenied";
options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

services.AddSession();
services.AddSingleton<MySharedDataViewComponent>();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
// The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseSession();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

});
}
```

Now I used the below expression for deleting cookie after closing the browser.

```
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{

IsPersistent = false

};
```

The above expression works and it deletes cookie if all I close all the tabs and browser.

Comment: You could detect tab closing in JavaScript.But I do not suggest you did such operation.Why did you want to delete cookie when tab closing.I think if one tab close and cookie delete,this may cause any other problems while other tabs send request to the server side.

Comment: MinaMRM,  did you figure out? I have same req

Comment: I understood that if any tab is opened and you close the tab that runs the application then the cookie won’t be deleted, you can just set your program whenever you close the browser then the cookie will be deleted. Also it is possible to set expiration time that is when you don’t use the program in a specific time then it deletes the cookie.